# How can you hide the fact your server has a WCF service located at MyService.svc

Tags: iis-6, wcf

Is there a way to serve up a custom "Sorry not found" page from a direct access request to a WCF Service (.svc file) on a server running IIS 6.0, and .NET 3.5 SP1.

I have a requirement that my service in a Production environment is not discoverable. The requirement states that WSDL publishing should be off, and the request also states that when directly accessing the MyService.svc file via a HTTP Get Request that a "Sorry Not found" page is displayed instead.

I have no problem disabling the metadata in the config file.

`<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />`

But I can't figure out a way to not show the default .svc page.

**SERVICE**
This is a Windows© Communication Foundation service.

**Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled.**

If you have access to the service, you can enable metadata publishing by completing the following steps to modify your web or application configuration file:
...

Also posted at [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633675/how-can-you-hide-the-fact-your-server-has-a-wcf-service-located-at-myservice-svc).

Comment: You can hide the .svc extension: http://west-wind.com/weblog/posts/570695.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just restrict access using your clientaccesspolicy.xml or crossdomainpolicy.xml files?

You could also just host the service on a different port, if you're worried that someone will wander onto http://yoursite/service.svc

Example of a crossdomainpolicy.xml from yourdomain.com

```
<cross-domain-policy>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all" /> 
  <allow-access-from domain="*.yourdomain.com" secure="false" /> 
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="false" /> 
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: No, it is a valid service and needs to work for HTTP Post, just not HTTP Get on the direct .svc page.
Yes, it is a strange request, but Security Teams can be strange themselves.

I personally don't think it is possible.